# How to make server-side domain models available to client-side web browser?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, client-side, server-side, domain-model

In my web application utilizing Spring MVC, I have a rich domain model.
I would like to make this domain model available to a client web browser. For example, as my domain model includes a class `Person` with methods `Set<Person> getFriends()` and `DateTime getBirthday()`, I would like to use these methods on the client side. Usage scenarios include

- dynamically updating the visiting browser's HTML to list all friends when requested so by the user, or
- sort `persons` in the HTML by their birthday.

Please notice I'm not looking here for accessing my domain model in the "view rendering stage" (e.g. JSP). I am looking here for accessing my domain model on my web application's users' browsers. So for example I don't want to sort `Person` instances during the "view rendering stage". I want this sorting to happen later, on my user's browser.

What are solutions to my challenge?

Comment: you could use javascript MVC framework to recreate your models in js

Comment: **1.** Make sure you require authentication to your API. **2.** Look into `HATEOAS` and `REST`.  I have heard that [exposing your domain model](http://java.dzone.com/articles/domain-model-rest-anti-pattern) can be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript - there are frameworks that could help ease the burden. The scenario you have described is an Ajax call to some service. You could represent the data as json which would be lightweight and easy enough to add to the page using javascript.

Comment: As I understand it, with this solution I would need to recreate my already existing Java domain model in JavaScript. I further would need to make sure both representations stay in sync. And finally, I'd need to make sure there is a "JSON-JVM bridge" for both worlds to interact. Are there tools out there that automatically generate JavaScript equivalences to my Java domain classes and that automatically generate "JSON-JVM bridges" for me?

Comment: @Abdull To truly have your domain model in the browser 'as-is' you'd need to have an applet and send it across the wire - this isn't what you've described. My thought was that you would have a web service that returns json data. You could then convert that data into whatever structure made sense for your page. I'm not sure you need to exactly replicate your domain model, but I guess this depends on your requirements. I don't know of any tools to do this for you, but since the language contstructs are different, I expect it would be difficult

Comment: Grails has the JSON-JVM bridge that you need built into its Domain model.

Ember.js automatically keeps the data in sync between the browser and the backend.

There's no tool to automagically take your Java domain classes and generate Javascript equivalents, but using Ember makes it stupidly trivial (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

[Ember.js](http://emberjs.com) (specifically its [Models](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/)) and [Grails](http://grails.org) do **exactly** what you want when used together.  I'm sure that you can use any Java framework to do this, but Grails makes it **stupidly** easy.  Below are a few patterns to get you started, but [here's a complete example app](https://github.com/kentbutler/todomvc-grails-emberjs)!

Domain class:

```
class Person {
    String name
}
```

Controller:

```
class PersonsController {
    def index() { render (["person": Person.list()] as JSON) }
}
```

Ember.js App:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 11,
   adapter:  DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    namespace: 'app'
  })
)};
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
)};
```

In your browser, this single command will populate the in-browser data store by fetching `/app/persons` from the backend.  Modifying the in-browser instances will automatically HTTP `POST` the updated instance to your Controller.

```
App.Person.list()
```

You'll want to check out [my answer on getting the two to play together in perfect harmony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307576/how-to-make-ember-js-behave-with-grails-controller-names) for more complex applications.

Answer (score 2):

Abdull have you looked at GWT(Google  Web ToolKit) http://bit.ly/YYz2Yx?

Here is some sample code that illustrates creation of client side components.

e.g. loading contacts

```
            VerticalPanel contactsPanel = new VerticalPanel();
            contactsPanel.setSpacing(4);
            String[] contactNames = constants.cwStackPanelContacts();
            String[] contactEmails = constants.cwStackPanelContactsEmails();
            for (int i = 0; i < contactNames.length; i++) {
              final String contactName = contactNames[i];
              final String contactEmail = contactEmails[i];
              final Anchor contactLink = new Anchor(contactName);
              contactsPanel.add(contactLink)
```

http://bit.ly/12MOhZQ (for actual code sample)

Answer (score 0):

If you were not limited to the browser - and thus javascript, I'd scream RMI about now. Luckily, there seems to be a solution to make it work. I have not tried it, but it might be worthwhile:

> jabsorb is a simple, lightweight JSON-RPC library for communicating
>   between Javascript running in the browser and Java running on the
>   server. It allows you to call Java methods on the server from
>   Javascript as if they were local, complete with automatic parameter
>   and result serialization.

https://code.google.com/p/jabsorb/

Answer (score 0):

Two populer javascript MVC frameworks:

http://backbonejs.org/
http://knockoutjs.com/

You can try them personally. suggestion are always subjective, your choice are always subjective as well. so just feel it yourself.