# How to Make Ember.js Behave with Grails Controller Names?

Tags: grails, ember.js, ember-data

Grails is pretty powerful, and lets you turn your Domain objects into JSON with a single statement (`object as JSON`).  Unfortunately, this is not sufficient to interact with Ember.js for a few reasons.

How can I make Grails play nicely with Ember.js?

Answer (score 12):

Good question, self!

Ember.js, and its auto-AJAX-in-browser-data-store ninjitsu expect the URL to look a certain way, and the JSON to look a certain way.  Due to the way that each tool works, it's easier to make conforming changes to *both* sides of the equation!

### What Grails Provides

For a Domain class `MyCoolDomainClass` with a controller `MyCoolDomainClassController`, Grails wants to provide the URL `/app/myCoolDomainClass`.  If you set up the controller to contain something along the lines of:

```
def index() { render MyCoolDomainClass.list() as JSON }
```

You'll get a response that looks like:

`[{ id: 1, name: "Bob"}, {id: 2, name: "Sally"}]`

### What Ember Wants

In Ember.js, you might create a Model with the same properties.  By leveraging `ember-data`, you can easily hook up the Data Store in the browser with your backend.  Unfortunately, what Ember.js wants is different.  It expects the the url `/my_cool_domain_class` to provide the data:

`{ mycooldomainclass: [ { id: 1, name: "Bob"}, {id: 2, name "Sally"}] }`

### Reconciling

**UPDATE**: I've created a [`ember-data-grails` repo on Github](https://github.com/jwklomp/ember-data-grails) which takes care of all of these modifications for you, and demonstrates how to make a controller that plays along nicely!

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please add a comment explaining why you think this is not a good answer

Comment: Great work Zach. This really helped me start with Ember and Grails. Tks

Answer (score 0):

I'm begining with emberjs, working for two years in Grails 1.3.7, so this is what would I do so you can get:

```
{ mycooldomainclass: [ { id: 1, name: "Bob"}, {id: 2, name "Sally"}] }
```

It's simple enough:

```
def c = Product.createCriteria()
def products = c.list{
    //your criteria
}
res = products.collect {a ->
  return [id:a.id, name:a.name, price:a.price, categoryname: a.category.name]
}

response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" )
response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" )
response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 )
render(contentType: 'text/json') {[
    'mycooldomainclass': res
]}
```